# JavaScript - Attaching Multiple Strings Together

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I have a string array variable called 'myAttachmentArray[]' which holds different figures like this:

[0] - 50000

[1] - 51010

[2] - 52000

[3] - 50010

And the array size is dependent on an int variable called 'squadNumbers'

What I want to do, is to place all the 'myAttachmentArray[]' into another string variable called 'currentAttachments', but with a ',' in between each array value.

So, currentAttachments would = 50000,51010,52000,50010 ...

The only problem is that the array size is dynamic, so I can't do:

currentAttachments = myAttachmentArray[0]+","+myAttachmentArray[1]...

So I tried a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= (squadNumbers - 1); i++){
    currentAttachments = currentAttachments + myAttachmentArray[i] + ",";
}
```

But I still don't get what I want ...Please help

Comment: @MikeRobinson: Well, and reading the question and picking up the `squadNumbers` thing. ;-)

Comment: `i<=(squadNumbers-1)` is functionally identical to the more concise & expressive `i<squadNumbers`. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```
currentAttachments = myAttachmentArray.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's really an array, you can use [`join`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.5):

```
myAttachmentArray.length = squadNumbers;
var str = myAttachmentArray.join(",");
```

That makes sure the array length is the value from `squadNumbers`, and then uses `join` to join together those entries. Each entry will be turned into a string, then joined using the delimiter you specify.

(But why is the number of entries in `squadNumbers` rather than just in `myAttachmentArray.length` in the first place?)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
currentAttachments = myAttachmentArray.join(",")
```